# How to count number of XML nodes that contain specific value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I am looking for how to count the nodes in an XML file that contain a value of "No" as well as the total number of elements.

I have the element count working fine, but I am not sure of the logic to look inside the XML for a value to count.

To get the total count I am using:

```
    XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
    readDoc.Load(MapPath("Results.xml"));
    int count = readDoc.SelectNodes("root/User").Count;
    lblResults.Text = count.ToString();
```

Below is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <User>
    <URL>http://www.example.com</URL>
    <JSEnabled>Yes</JSEnabled>
  </User>
  <User>
   <URL>http://www.example.com</URL>
   <JSEnabled>Yes</JSEnabled>
 </User>
 <User>
   <URL>http://www.example.com</URL>
   <JSEnabled>Yes</JSEnabled>
 </User>
 <User>
   <URL>http://www.example.com</URL>
   <JSEnabled>Yes</JSEnabled>
 </User>
 <User>
   <URL>http://www.example.com</URL>
   <JSEnabled>No</JSEnabled>
 </User>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
readDoc.Load(MapPath("Results.xml"));
int count = readDoc.SelectNodes("root/User").Count;
lblResults.Text = count.ToString();
int NoCount = readDoc.SelectNodes("JSEnabled[. = \"No\"]").Count;
```

Good reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx

Comment: This got me what I asked for but after reading that reference link, I was able to get even more then I was originally looking for. Thanks much

Comment: `NoCount` should probably be an `XmlNodeList` instead of an `int`.  Alternatively, you should use `readDoc.SelectNodes("JSEnabled[. = \"No\"]").Count`.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking for how to count the
>   nodes in an XML file that contain a
>   value of "No"

In XPath:

```
count(/root/User[JSEnabled = 'No'])
```

> as well as the total number of
>   elements.

That you already have it:

```
count(/root/User)
```

Or use the expression for selecting the nodes and any DOM method to count Node Set Result members.