# Finding count of a keyword in an XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, winforms

Xml can have format like this

```
<root>
    <child1>
        Value1
    </child1>
    <child2>
            <child3>
                Value2
            </child3>
            <child4>
                    <child5>
                        Value1
                    </child5>
            </child4>
    </child2>
    <child6>
        Value1
    </child6>
</root>
```

Here Value1 is written 3times, so count should be 3.

Or Xml can have format like this:

```
<root>
    <child1 value="Value1" />
    <child2 value="Value2"/>
    <child3 value="Value1" />
    <child4 value="Value1"/>
    <child5 value="Value3" />
    <child6 value="Value4"/>    
</root>
```

Here Value1 has count 3.

So Xml can have any format, I want to count a particular keyword count in an xml.

Please guide !

> Edit: The question is not possible duplicate of the link you have mentioned, here I don't know the depth of the xml e.g. it could have
>   one child or many children in which a keyword may or may not present.
>   I want to traverse all the nodes without know the depth of each node**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to count number of XML nodes that contain specific value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650899/how-to-count-number-of-xml-nodes-that-contain-specific-value)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of this link @vahidkargar , I have edited the question

Comment: That means the question is how to count the nodes which has searchstring matching with either attribute or value?

Comment: @HariPrasad yes.. we will enter some keyword in a variable and based on that we need to check the number of occurrences of that variable. Yes the keyword could be present as an attribute or a value.

Comment: @Rahul I added an answer with what was explained, you could check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `XDocument` for this.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(filename);       
var count = doc.Descendants()                                                     // flattens the structure
              .Where(x=> (!x.HasElements &&((string)x.Value).Trim() == "Value1")
                            || (x.Attribute("value") != null 
                                && x.Attribute("value").Value == "Value1")
                         )                                                        // filter based on value
              .Count();                                                           // Take count
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JLf3YV)

Comment: Awesome Hari ! Just want to ask one more thing, can we change this attribute from "value" to all the attributes ? Thanks

Comment: Could you please help me with that code as well ? as I don't know what to write in place of "value" to check with all the attributes.

Comment: Just modify the condition to  `(!x.HasElements &&((string)x.Value).Trim() == "Value1") || x.Attributes().Any(a=>a.Value == "Value1"))`

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument readDoc = new XmlDocument();
readDoc.Load(MapPath("your xml path"));

int NoCount = readDoc.SelectNodes("child[. = \"Value1\"]").Count;
```

this you can check for all values,(e.g.Value1,Valu2 etc.)

Comment: you mentioned completely unrelated link from MSDN!

Comment: please explain whats the relevance of 'XPath Examples' and Finding count of a keyword?

Answer (score 0):

You can see below code. I am not good in C#, therefore the code is written in VB.

```vb
Public Class Form1
Private Function SearchKeyword(s_Node As String, s_Keyword As String) As Integer
    Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim i_CurPos As Integer = 1
    Dim s_InnerText As String
    Dim s_File As String = "E:\test.xml"
    doc.Load(s_File)
    Dim nodelist As XmlNodeList = doc.SelectNodes(s_Node)
    For Each node As XmlElement In nodelist
        s_InnerText = node.InnerText

        For i = 1 To CInt(Len(s_InnerText) / Len(s_Keyword))
            If InStr(i_CurPos, s_InnerText, s_Keyword) > 0 Then
                SearchKeyword += 1
                i_CurPos = InStr(i_CurPos, s_InnerText, s_Keyword) + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return SearchKeyword
End Function

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    MsgBox(SearchKeyword("root", "Value1"))
End Sub
End Class
```