# How to count XML tag with specific value to produce a summary C#; ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am having difficulty trying to figure out how to count a XML tag with a certain value. Then put that into a text box. I have gotten as far as de-serialising the data in the xml file but cannot figure out how to go about getting a summary
The following code I have so far is:

code behind file: index.aspx.cs

```
protected void summaryReport ()
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Xml2CSharp.Registrations));
    FileStream fileStream = null;

    try
    {
        fileStream = new FileStream(fullFileName, FileMode.Open);
    }
    catch
    {
        txtSummary.Text = "Error: Xml file not Found.";
        return;
    }

    Registrations registrationList = (Registrations)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();

    txtSummary.Text = "There are " + ...numberofattendants... + " People attending the conference.";
}
```

XML file: registrations.xml

```
<registrations>
      <Registration>
         <id>1</id>
         <fullName>Keiran Bernal</fullName>
         <emailAddress>k.bernal@gmail.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>conference only</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>2</id>
         <fullName>Cordelia Pierce</fullName>
         <emailAddress>c.pierce@outlook.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>conference and Dinner</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>no</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>3</id>
         <fullName>Zachery Guy</fullName>
         <emailAddress>z.guy@yahoo.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>conference only</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <Registration>
         <id>4</id>
         <fullName>Kiana Hawworth</fullName>
         <emailAddress>k.hawworth@bigpond.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>conference and Dinner</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>no</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
   </registrations>
```

Helper Class: registrations.cs

```
namespace Xml2CSharp
{

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Registration")]
    public class Registration
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
        public string id { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "fullName")]
        public string fullName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "emailAddress")]
        public string emailAddress { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "registrationType")]
        public string registrationType { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "attendingSocialEvent")]
        public string attendingSocialEvent { get; set; }

        public Registration()
        {
            this.id = null;
            this.fullName = null;
            this.emailAddress = null;
            this.registrationType = null;
            this.attendingSocialEvent = null;
        }

        public Registration(string id, string fullName, string emailAddress, string registrationType, string attendingSocialEvent)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.fullName = fullName;
            this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
            this.registrationType = registrationType;
            this.attendingSocialEvent = attendingSocialEvent;
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "registrations")]
    public class Registrations
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Registration")]
        public List<Registration> registrationList { get; set; }

        public Registrations()
        {
            this.registrationList = new List<Registration>();
        }
    }  
}
```

ASP.NET Form: index.cs

```
<form>
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server" Text="Summary:" CssClass="lblsummary"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="txtsummary" Columns="50" Rows="5"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
</form>
```

My aim is to count the amount of XML tags  with the value "Yes" and then put that in to a summary. I believe I will have to put that in to a variable somehow but not sure how and how only count the ones with the value "Yes"

Comment: Found a solution that was posted before this is what worked for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4650961/10498504

Answer (score 0):

After deserializing the XML into a `Registrations` object, you can use Linq to count the registrations:

```
Registrations registrations = ....;

// check if registrations.registrationList is not null before doing this
int count = registrations.registrationList.Count(x =>
    x.attendingSocialEvent.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

Or, as an alternative, add a non-serializable property to the `Registrations` class as follows:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "registrations")]
public class Registrations
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public int CountAttendances
    {
        get
        {
            if (registrationList == null)
            {
                return 0;
            }

            int count = registrationList.Count(x => x.attendingSocialEvent.Equals("yes", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

            return count;
        }
    }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Registration")]
    public List<Registration> registrationList { get; set; }

    public Registrations()
    {
        this.registrationList = new List<Registration>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to deserialize to POCOs if counting is all you want to do...

You can count the `"yes"` respondents using LINQ as follows:

```
var xmlStr = @"<registrations>
      <Registration>
         <id>1</id>
         <fullName>Keiran Bernal</fullName>
         <emailAddress>k.bernal@gmail.com</emailAddress>
         <registrationType>conference only</registrationType>
         <attendingSocialEvent>yes</attendingSocialEvent>
      </Registration>
      <!-- SNIP -->
   </registrations>";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var numYes = doc.Descendants("Registration")
                .Count(r => string.Equals((string)r.Element("attendingSocialEvent"), 
                                          "yes", 
                                          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
```